# Redis Slave Master connections fails Slave logs show: Unable to connect to MASTER: Permission denied

Tags: redis, centos7

I have followed the instructions on how to set up a redis master server cluster but after I am done I get am not able to see why the servers are not able to see one another.
this is the second build I put together and I am stuck on the same spot. I could really use some help I never worked on REDIS before and I could use some guidance.

USING CENTOS7 Redis version

when i check the redis slave logs I get the following

> [20671] 12 Jan 15:48:02.369 * Connecting to MASTER 10.10.10.10:6379
>
> [20671] 12 Jan 15:48:02.369 # Unable to connect to MASTER: Permission denied

The config files are using the same exact password for both master and slave.
and just to test I gave the default directory full control for the  redis working directory files and folder
Tested ports and they are working fine,

I also get the following when I run INFO when connecting to REDIS Slave

```
Replication

role:slave
master_host:10.10.10.11.
master_port:6379
master_link_status:down
master_last_io_seconds_ago:-1
master_sync_in_progress:0
slave_repl_offset:1
master_link_down_since_seconds:1452631759
slave_priority:100
slave_read_only:1
connected_slaves:0
master_repl_offset:0
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0
```

INFO from MASTER NODE:

```
Replication

role:master
connected_slaves:0
master_repl_offset:0
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0
```

Both servers are running on CENTOS 7

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue when setting up a Redis cluster on CentOS 7 at AWS, and it was in fact due to SELinux being enabled. You can verify that this is your issue by checking the contents of `/var/log/audit.log`.

To allow Redis replication with SELinux, run the following commands as root to update the security policy. As you will likely be using `Sentinel` to manage the cluster, the necessary policies for `Sentinel` master and slaves is included as well.

**Folder for policy files**

> Location to save new policy files

```
mkdir -p ~/.selinux
```

**Redis Replication Policy**

> Allow data replication to slaves, include on master as well as it may become a slave at some point

```
cat <<SELINUX > ~/.selinux/redis_repl.te
# create new
module redis_repl 1.0;

require {
        type redis_port_t;
        type redis_t;
        class tcp_socket name_connect;
}

#============= redis_t ==============
allow redis_t redis_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect;
SELINUX

checkmodule -m -M -o ~/.selinux/redis_repl.mod ~/.selinux/redis_repl.te
semodule_package --outfile ~/.selinux/redis_repl.pp --module ~/.selinux/redis_repl.mod
semodule -i ~/.selinux/redis_repl.pp
```

**Redis Sentinel Master/Slave Policy, all Redis nodes**

> Allow Sentinel HA traffic on the Redis master/slave nodes

```
cat <<SELINUX > ~/.selinux/redis_ha.te
# create new
module redis_ha 1.0;

require {
        type etc_t;
        type redis_t;
        class file write;
}

#============= redis_t ==============
allow redis_t etc_t:file write;
SELINUX

checkmodule -m -M -o ~/.selinux/redis_ha.mod ~/.selinux/redis_ha.te
semodule_package --outfile ~/.selinux/redis_ha.pp --module ~/.selinux/redis_ha.mod
semodule -i ~/.selinux/redis_ha.pp
```

**Redis Sentinel Server Policy, all Sentinel nodes**

> Allow Sentinel HA traffic from the Sentinel nodes.
>
> ***Note that you may need to change the Sentinel port if you aren't using the 26379 default.***

```
# Allow Sentinel Port
semanage port -a -t redis_port_t -p tcp 26379

# Allow Sentinel Server
cat <<SELINUX > ~/.selinux/redis_sentinel.te
# create new
module redis_sentinel 1.0;

require {
        type redis_port_t;
        type etc_t;
        type redis_t;
        class tcp_socket name_connect;
        class file write;
}

#============= redis_t ==============
allow redis_t redis_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect;
allow redis_t etc_t:file write;
SELINUX

checkmodule -m -M -o ~/.selinux/redis_sentinel.mod ~/.selinux/redis_sentinel.te
semodule_package --outfile ~/.selinux/redis_sentinel.pp --module ~/.selinux/redis_sentinel.mod
semodule -i ~/.selinux/redis_sentinel.pp
```

**Restart Redis and Sentinel**

```
service restart redis
service restart redis-sentinel
```

Answer (score 0):

To @otaviofcs point, you're likely running into an SELinux issue. If you look in /var/log/audit/audit.log, I suspect you'll see alot of logging that looks like this:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1465349491.812:28458): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=30676 comm="redis-server" dest=6379 scontext=system_u:system_r:redis_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:redis_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
```

If so, you can either dive into the bowels of SELinux policy management or take the easy road: set SELinux targeted policy to permissive:

```
setenforce permissive
```

Note that you'll need to set the same in `/etc/selinux/config` by changing the line with `SELINUX=` to `SELINUX=permissive`.

Comment: I would recommend "diving into the bowels" rather than disabling it entirely - safety.... first? See my answer for the correct way to set up the selinux policies needed for Redis replication.

Comment: Agreed. That was my implication about "take the easy road."

Answer (score 0):

two "new experience points"
The config is in the 2 ends of the conecction,

to add "personalized" port you can use semanage
sudo semanage port -a -t redis_port_t -p tcp 8014